# Flutter: how to access context from Dismissible onDismissed

Tags: flutter, redux

I'm trying to implement undo for a Dismissible list item in Flutter, and having problems accessing a BuildContext.

I have a flutter list, where each item is a card. The card is wrapped in a [Dismissible](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible), which allows the user to swipe to dismiss the card. Dismissible automatically removes the item from the list. Dismissible also has an onDismissed event - I'm using this event to update the item in Redux state store (setting an isDismissed flag to true), then show a snackBar which contains an UNDO button.

This is where I'm running into problems. I want the UNDO button to restore the item, by dispatching another action to the Redux store to set isDismissed to false. To do this I need a context, from which to get the store dispatcher. However when I try with the below code, I get an error when clicking on UNDO:

> Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe

```
class ProductCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Product product;

  const ProductCard(this.product);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dismissible(
      key: Key(product.id.toString()),

      onDismissed: (direction) {
        StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context).dispatch(DismissAction(product));

        // Then show a snackbar to allow undo
        Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
                content: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(child: Text("Dismissed ${product.title}"),),
                    FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        // THIS IS WHERE I GET THE ERROR
                        StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context).dispatch(UndoDismissAction(product));
                      },
                      child: Text("UNDO"),
                    )
                  ],
                )
            )
        );
      },

      child: Card(
        child: ...
      )
    );
  }
}
```

From what I've read, I think what is going on is that the line `StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context)` inside the undo button's onPressed action is trying to use a context which belongs to the Card, but because the card has been removed from the list, it no longer exists.

I'm not sure how to do work around this. I've read about flutter keys, and think the answer may be to start passing around some kind of global key, but I can't quite get my head around how that works. I gave it a go and ran into another problem with `'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' was called on null`. Are keys the solution to this problem? If so where do I create the key, do I pass it in to the widget, what type of key should I use etc, or is there a better solution?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract a single copy of the store into a local variable, which will then get captured by all the lambdas below.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var store = StoreProvider.of<AppState>(context);
    return Dismissible(
    ...
         store.dispatch(DismissAction(product));
```